# How to find the Partner Community and Company Communities total and used Licenses

Tags: apex, soql, licenses, userlicense

I am working on a requirement and thereby I was trying to fetch the used and unused license statusfor a particular license. I am able to check the Salesforce Total and Used License through internal logic , However Unable to get the Partner Community and Company Communities license information through query.

Is there any way to do that. [image]